# Is syslog a logging standard, or a protocol standard?

Tags: definition, standards, syslog, rfc, rsyslog

Syslog is a network protocol as described in RFC 5424 and RFC 3164 before that.

-AND-

Syslog is a standard in the *nix world. It's how you do logging. Even on just the local machine, UDP packets are never created. (Right?) The protocol, and the RFC, do not apply here.

What is Syslog predominantly, a protocol or a logging standard? Why?

I'm asking this so that I can update the Wikipedia page with the relevant information. In editing the page, do I focus on the protocol or the standard. It's not possible to do both. The answer to this question will be taken into account whether the page needs to be split into [Syslog] and [Syslog protocol] or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syslog names an event notification system which originated with [BSD UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution). There are two standard interfaces to it.

One interface is [in the UNIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/syslog.html). It consists of the `openlog()`, `setlogmask()`, `syslog()`, and `closelog()` functions, and the definitions in `syslog.h`. Applications can use this interface to create events. Events might go to a file, a console, a list of users, or a remote host; this is not determined by the standard. In Linux, the disposition of events is handled by the [`syslogd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd) process, following the local policy defined in the file [`/etc/syslog.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf).

The other interface is described by [RFC 3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164) and updated in [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424). It consists of a protocol for transmitting events to a remote host with UDP. Applications can use this interface to create events, but the more common user of the syslog protocol is `syslogd` itself, when it is forwarding events to a remote host.

It is wrong to say that UDP syslog packets are never created by UNIX hosts. When there are several hosts to manage, it is common practice to funnel some or all of the events to a designated host, so that there is one error log to monitor instead of many.

Comment: Will accept as answer if no better answers arrive in a few days. Good copy/paste material there. Would be perfect if more sources.

Comment: What sources would be good, in addition to the UNIX standard and the relevant RFCs and Linux man pages that are already sourced?

Comment: Something along the lines of the history of syslog. How the syslog() function transformed into the syslog protocol over time. Important events int that history. Hope I'm not asking too much, but you asked. : )

Comment: You ask how the syslog() function transformed into the syslog protocol over time, but I think that is the wrong question because they were developed together. As I explained in my answer, syslog() is the usual way to create an event, and the syslog protocol is the usual way to forward an event to a central place. Now as for a written history of syslog that one could cite as a source here or use as a source for the Wikipedia article, I am not aware of one. You could contact Eric Allman <http://www.neophilic.com/~eric/> or look in the Bat Book <http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565928398.do>.